# Turning the second display off and on

Tags: delphi, winapi, display

I am using Delphi 2010.

There is a cash register with two displays: the main (for the cashier) and auxiliary (for the buyer).

I need to enable and disable the second display from the program.

When I use the following command, the main display is turned off:

```
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);
```

Which command can turn off (turn on) just the second display?

Comment: Just a guess, but I think that only the monitor the window is displayed on is controlled (why else you would need a window handle??.). On the other hand according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendnotifymessagea HWND_BROADCAST means all the all top-level windows. Maybe the buyer display has no windows on or they are not the top-level?... I'd try sending the same message to the window on the buyers display directly. Good luck!

Comment: But how do I send the same message to the buyer's monitor?

Comment: My guess is that `SC_MONITORPOWER` was designed a few decades ago, when you only had a single monitor connected to your computer. Today, I bet there is a nice, fully fledged monitor (Win32) API you can use.

Comment: Is disabling second monitor even good approach here? I'm guessing you are trying to prevent burn-in effect on second monitor. Why I'm doubting this is good approach in solving the problem. When you turn specific monitor off this is done by disabling the signal to such monitor so it goes into stand-by mode. The problem is that depending on the monitor it could take even few seconds for monitor to turn back on from this stand-by mode. This can become annoying to the customer as it needs to wait for monitor to turn back on before he sees the price. ...

Comment: ... So alternative solution for this might be just creating a specific black window that covers the whole area of second monitor when you don't need anything to be shown to the customer. Or you can go and shown some advertisement from your or your customer company on this second monitor until a final price needs to be shown to the customer. I have already seen the last solution implemented in many shops that are using dual monitor registers provided that second monitor is full fledged monitor and not just a numerical LCD display..

Comment: Thank you for your response. I wanted to go the simple route of turning off the screen when the cash register is on standby, and turning it on when a sale occurs.
Unfortunately, I have no experience with copying any form to a second screen. I would appreciate it if someone could give me a hint or direction.

Comment: @Mefodiy , I've created an application with 2 forms, added a button with code `SendMessage(Self.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);` to eatch of them. I place the forms on both of my monitors. No matter the screen the form I click the button is on, both of my monitors turn off. After moving my mouse I must log-in again. I can't explain the behaviour you observe. Maybe your client display does not support turning off by windows (unlikely, but no other ideas)...

Comment: I don't think Windows has the ability to turn off just one monitor. Any monitors enabled for the desktop are controlled simultaneously.